# Scala Enumeration Data As String?

Tags: scala

Is possible that an enumeration data type in Scala can be implemented as String as

```
enum Currency {CAD, EUR, USD }
```

in Java instead of

```
object Currency extends Enumeration {

  val CAD, EUR, USD = Value
}
```

which data value is binary?

I write a same functionality in both Java and Scala. The enumeration data is saved into database. The Java version works nicely with String value, but not the Scala version which is binary data.

Answer (score 10):

You can do:

```
object Currency extends Enumeration {
  type Currency = String
  val CAD = "CAD"
  val EUR = "EUR"
  val USD = "USD"
}
```

And then the underlying type of each is an actual `String`.

Comment: Extending `Enumeration` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks. That works either with or without Enumeration extension.

Comment: Is explicitly extending Enumeration bad though? Is it not more clear that it is an enum?

Comment: This example code seems to be misleading to me. It creates an empty `Enumeration` with 3 `String` constants that cannot be accessed through the `values` API; they don't have the `id` property and we can't get/set their order.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using toString.

```
Currency.Cad.toString() == "Cad"
Currency.withName("Cad") == Currency.Cad
```

Also if you want a readable format of your choice you can choose your string

```
object Currency extends Enumeration {
    val CAD = Value("Canadian Dollar")
    val EUR, USD = Value
}
```

See [this blog post](https://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-enums/) for full info.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution w/o use of `Enumeration`:

```
object Currency {
  val CAD = "CAD"
  val EUR = "EUR"
  val USD = "USD"
}
```

And then the underlying type of each is an actual `String`. Usage in the REPL:

```
scala> val currency = Currency.USD
currency: String = USD
```

*Reasoning*: using `extends Enumeration` and `type Currency = String` as in the most voted answer apparently have no real benefit and could lead to unexpected results; on the given example, if we called `Currency.values` we would get an empty set. See the [Enumeration](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Enumeration.html) API.

See also: https://www.baeldung.com/scala/enumerations

Comment: This do not insure exhaustive case matching